# google pay api: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have integrated google pay in my app. But when I query product details, it always returns an empty list. So I called the interface in the Google Play Developer API to check, and it returned a 403 error, prompting:unlinked.

But it is confirmed that there is an association between the api and the google account. I have also tried the solutions of other friends on the Internet, but I have not been able to solve it. I would like to ask where else may be the problem? Thanks

I cannot query products by calling the queryProductDetailsAsync method. Next, I tried to simulate the request at https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/inappproducts/get, but it returned an unlinked error, the details are as follows:
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The project ID used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}